# Scalar sub queries

Tags: mysql, sql, subquery

```
CREATE TABLE t1 (s1 INT, s2 CHAR(5) NOT NULL);
INSERT INTO t1 VALUES(100, 'abcde');
SELECT (SELECT s2 FROM t1);
```

when i am executing in MySql DB its giving syntax error like 1065
the select statement is not executing,
this is call scalar sub queries according to MySql
follow link for more info
http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/scalar-subqueries.html

Answer (score 4):

To return a scalar value your subquery must return ONE row and ONE field. So you should limit rows in your subquery using WHERE or using MySQL LIMIT statement. For example:

```
SELECT (select s2 FROM t1 limit 1);
```

[SQLFiddle example](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/99ce4/3)

Answer (score 2):

You don't have a `FROM` clause in your select statement:

```
SELECT (SELECT s2 FROM t1)
FROM ...?
```

Note that this is only going to work if there is one row in `t1`. Otherwise you will need some way of getting the one row from `t1` you need:

```
SELECT (SELECT s2 FROM t1 WHERE ...)
FROM ...
```

---

A valid example of this kind of query in action would be something like:

```
SELECT (SELECT s2 FROM t1 WHERE s1 = 100), t2.id, t2.name
FROM t2;
```